# Spinning a new java thread to do db work for better UI responsiveness

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have an old application, it uses jdbc to do access to db.
I have a page that handles edits to a record, and I was thinking of spinning a new thread when the save button is hit, so the user does not have to wait for the response.

Are there any things I need to be concerned about in doing this?

Comment: There is much left out of this question. What GUI library for instance? What your expectations of a background thread are (for instance it won't make the db access any faster)? What you've tried? How it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling the workflow in the asynchronous model is what I'd be concerned about.

1. What would the application do in the case of failure or success?
2. Could the user continue without caring if his previous action succeeded or failed?

Cannot comment on the technical issues without knowing more about the system architecture.